# QImage Resize Event

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I have a simple paint application, but when I resize window the image is being deleted an I want to keep it. I tried using image.scaled(current size) but it doesn't work.

```
qDebug() << "Resized.";

CurrentSize = event->size();

QImage newImage(CurrentSize, QImage::Format_RGB32);
Image = newImage;
Image.fill(Qt::white);
IsDrawing = false;

this->update();
```

Comment: From the little code you posted it is not clear what exactly you are doing, nor where your problem lies. It depends on how your drawing is implemented, which is unknown. Also, the code you posted makes no sense - you create a new empty image, then you set some other image to become that new empty image, and then you fill it with white. How is any of that supposed to be of any use?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the code you provided is inside a method, in which case newImage is created on the stack, and will go out of scope (and have the destructor called) when the method is exited.

Creating it on the heap instead (`new QImage`) will prevent that, but you then need to manage the object's lifetime.  Qt's `parent` is usually helpful for that.

Comment: `QImage` does not inherit `QObject`, and can not have a parent

Comment: @wasthishelpful Nonsense. QImage inherts QPaintDevice inherits QWidget inherits QObject. Everything in Qt inherits QObject. From the documentation: "The QObject class is the base class of all Qt objects."

Comment: Actually @wasthishelpful is right.  QImage inherits from QPaintDevice, but QPaintDevice is _inherited by_ QWidget, it doesn't inherit from QWidget.  Notice there is no QObject *parent constructor parameter for QImage.

Comment: There are many Qt classes that do not extend `QObject` and understandably so - it has a significant overhead. A few examples - QString, QList, QJSValue, QJsonObject...

Comment: `QImage` should be a member of the class, not created on the heap. Heap creation is an extra layer of indirection that forces you to do manual memory management and is an unnecessary complication. Do not suggest such hacks - they don't belong in modern C++, heck, they didn't even belong in Qt 4 - it already had value types that were easy to use.

Comment: Quite dubious that this answer should receive 4 upvotes for making an ungrounded assumption on basis of code that clearly was not property examined and presenting incorrect information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "simple" your simple paint application is, but I sense that you're overcomplicating things a bit.

Suppose that we have the following requirements for a paint canvas widget:

1. The image size tracks the widget size, and does so by cropping, not rescaling.
2. The widget can change its size freely.
3. Optionally, the image is never shrunk. This option is set by default.
4. Drawing is done when the left mouse button is depressed held down.
5. Right mouse button clears the image.
6. Line segments are drawn between the successive mouse positions.

An implementation that is correct and doesn't have gratuitous pessimizations is given below. Note the following:

1. The image is a user property of the widget. It can be set, read, and tracked. It'd be simple to e.g. connect `imageChanged` to a label's `setPixmap` and have a duplicate canvas display.
2. The `paintEvent` enforces the precondition of "there's a correctly sized image to paint" by calling `newImage`.
3. To change `QImage`'s size you have to create a new image, copy the contents using `QPainter::drawImage`, then swap the old one with the new one.
4. Due to simplicity of the paint tool, it's not necessary to track the painting/non-painting state explicitly.
5. The image can be safely cleared at any time, even when the left mouse button is depressed.
6. The widget ignores user interaction when it's disabled.
7. `setImage(std::move(someImage))` is an optimization for when `someImage` is not needed anymore: it saves a copy.
8. Relevant setters are also slots - this makes the widget more composable with other objects via signal-slot connections.
9. It is not necessary to explicitly schedule an update after a resize: Qt already does that.
10. Swapping out an image with an active painter is not allowed.
11. The change indication helper won't schedule an update if the widget's painting is underway. It would be a redundant update.
12. The canvas always draws itself fully and has top-left-corner-aligned contents. These facts should be indicated in widget's properties, as a performance optimization.
13. Checking `QImage::size()` takes care of null images - their size is null too.
14. The conspicuous absence of manual memory management isn't by chance but by design: there isn't a single `new` nor `delete` anywhere in the code. The compiler can do it all for you in this case. Prefer keeping member variables as values. E.g. a `QImage` should be held by value. It's a value class, there's no point to explicitly allocating it via `new`. In fact, it's a premature pessimization to do so.
15. Self-contained code examples should be small, minimal, and in a single file. You should have created such an example when asking the question.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/painting-app-48520925
#include <QtWidgets>

class PaintCanvas : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QImage image READ image WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged USER true)
   Q_PROPERTY(bool neverShrink READ neverShrink WRITE setNeverShrink)
   bool m_neverShrink = true;
   QImage m_image;
   QPoint m_lastPos;
   QPen m_pen{{Qt::red}, 3.0, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin};
   void indicateChange() {
      emit imageChanged(m_image);
      if (!this->paintingActive()) update();
   }
   void newImage() {
      auto newSize = m_neverShrink ? size().expandedTo(m_image.size()) : size();
      if (newSize == m_image.size())
         return;
      QImage new_image{newSize, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied};
      new_image.fill(Qt::white);
      QPainter p{&new_image};
      p.drawImage(0, 0, m_image);
      p.end();
      m_image.swap(new_image);
      indicateChange();
   }
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {
      QPainter p{this};
      newImage(); // ensure that there's something to paint
      p.drawImage(0, 0, m_image);
   }
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
      if (isEnabled() && event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton)
         clear();
      if (! isEnabled() || ! (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton))
         return;
      m_lastPos = event->pos();
      QPainter p{&m_image};
      p.setPen(m_pen);
      p.drawLine(m_lastPos, m_lastPos+QPoint{1,1});
      indicateChange();
   }
   void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
      if (! isEnabled() || ! (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton))
         return;
      QPainter p{&m_image};
      p.setPen(m_pen);
      p.drawLine(m_lastPos, event->pos());
      m_lastPos = event->pos();
      indicateChange();
   }
public:
   PaintCanvas(QWidget * parent = {}) : QWidget(parent) {
      setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
      setAttribute(Qt::WA_StaticContents);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void imageChanged(const QImage &);
   QImage image() const { return m_image; }
   Q_SLOT void setImage(const QImage & image) {
      m_image = image;
      indicateChange();
   }
   void setImage(QImage && image) {
      m_image.swap(image);
      indicateChange();
   }
   bool neverShrink() const { return m_neverShrink; }
   void setNeverShrink(bool n) { m_neverShrink = n; }
   Q_SLOT void clear() {
      m_image = {};
      newImage();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   PaintCanvas canvas;
   canvas.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```